# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sents'

Tags: spacy

How can I resolve this attribute error in spaCy?

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function
    from spacy.lang.en import English

nlp = English()
sentencizer = nlp.create_pipe("sentencizer")
nlp.add_pipe(sentencizer)
assert len(list(doc.sents)) == 2
```

This is the traceback:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-0459326012bf> in <module>
      5 sentencizer = nlp.create_pipe("sentencizer")
      6 nlp.add_pipe(sentencizer)
----> 7 assert len(list(doc.sents)) == 2

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sents'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to tokenize (split) sentences, below is a code sample using spaCy.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
raw_text = 'Hello, world. Here are two sentences.'
doc = nlp(raw_text)
sentences = [sent.string.strip() for sent in doc.sents]
assert len(sentences) == 2

print(sentences)
```

Output:

```
['Hello, world.', 'Here are two sentences.']
```

Comment: my goal is to split a review body in different sentences

Comment: if I want do that to a csv file ?

Comment: @kyrion First read with `pandas.read_csv()` then apply the code to each row on your review column.